# How to properly use ReadProcessMemory without raising warnings

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory, readprocessmemory

What is the correct way to use `ReadProcessMemory`?

I am currently using it like this:

```
DWORD read_mem(DWORD addr)
{
    DWORD buffer = 0x0;
    if (!ReadProcessMemory(phandle, LPCVOID(addr), &buffer, sizeof(DWORD), nullptr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

This causes a warning due to `addr` being wrongly casted.

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

Other example code I've seen such as [this](https://github.com/aixxe/osu-relax/blob/master/relax/src/functions.h) uses the same approach.

So what is the proper way to use this function without getting a warning?

Comment: Ad address would be a pointer. Why did you decide to use DWORD? And do you understand the warning? If not why are you asking about the solution before understanding the warning? Do you want to understand, or do you just want somebody to write the program for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry if the wording is wrong, I'm not a native english speaker. I'm asking which type is best to use here. You could use `INT_PTR` for the address for example but is that the right choice?

Comment: I'd use a pointer to represent a pointer

Comment: for pointer need use of `PVOID` or if need arithmetic operation(add, compare) with it - `PBYTE` or `ULONG_PTR`. your warning because *different size*. some time, when need convert `DWORD d` to pointer need use 2 type cast for avoid warning - `(PVOID)(ULONG_PTR)(d)` . look for [`ULongToPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384267(v=vs.85).aspx) implementation in `basetsd.h`. however need be very attentive with sign-extends or zero-extends 4 bytes `DWORD` to 8 byte `PVOID` - this can produce very worst error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*cast to pointer from integer **of different size***" - this means that `DWORD` and `void*` are different byte sizes, which can only happen if you are compiling your code for 64-bit, as they are the same byte size in a 32-bit compilation.

From the MSDN documentation, [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx):

> DWORD
>   A **32-bit** unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 4294967295 decimal.

A `DWORD` is simply not large enough to hold a 64-bit memory address (the [other code](https://github.com/aixxe/osu-relax/blob/master/relax/src/functions.h) you mention will similarly only work correctly in 32-bit).

Change `Addr` (and whatever code you are using to determine the value of `Addr`) to use `DWORD_PTR` instead:

> DWORD_PTR
>   An unsigned long type for **pointer precision**. Use when casting a pointer to a long type to perform pointer arithmetic. (Also commonly used for general 32-bit parameters that have been extended to 64 bits in 64-bit Windows.)

Then `Addr` will be the correct byte size whether you compile for 32-bit or 64-bit.